# python: update an existing sqlite db

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite

Have a python script that creates a sqlite database:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('some.db',detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Title(ID INT, ...)")
```

and then later populates the db with content from a list:

```
    <ID> = <whatever>
    <var1> = <you get the point>

    altogether = (ID, var1...)
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Title VALUES(?,?,...)", altogether)
    con.commit()
```

I now want to write a modified version of this script that takes an existing `some.db` and updates it, but only does so if the ID doesn't already exist in the database.

How do I:

1. open `some.db` for read/write to update values only
2. query the db to make sure that the `ID`of the `item` that I'm currently iterating through does not already exist in the db? The way that I'm currently populating variables is by making API calls to an external service that I'd like to be able to skip if the entry is already in my db.

Comment: I think you might want "INSERT IF NOT EXIST"

Answer (score 0):

1. Same way you already did.
2. Don't. Make the column `UNIQUE` and handle the exception on `INSERT`.